# Using REGEX With String Interpolation

Tags: c#, regex, string, entity-framework-core

I am currently facing a challenge passing a regex query to the FromSqlRaw method in EF Core `>=3.1`.

The FromSqlRaw treats the query as string interpolation. I want it to ignore this and accept the query as it is.

#### Sample regex to test with

`^.*([a-z]\\s*){3,4}([0-9]\\s*){3}([a-z]?){1}[^$].*$`

#### Example 2

`this.context.Mudal.FromSqlRaw(@"SELECT * FROM Mudal WHERE replace(BillRefNumber, ' ', '') regexp '^.*([a-z]\\s*){3,4}([0-9]\\s*){3}([a-z]?){1}[^$].*$';").ToList()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an ideal answer all I have to do is change from this `{1}` to this `{{1}}`. This acts as an escape from string interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using parameterization to pass the regular expression. Try the following:

```
string regexpression = @"^.*([a-z]\\s*){3,4}([0-9]\\s*){3}([a-z]?){1}[^$].*$";
var mylist = this.context.Mudal
   .FromSqlRaw(@"SELECT * FROM Mudal WHERE replace(BillRefNumber, ' ', '') regexp {0};", 
      regexpression)
   .ToList();
```

Comment: Could you add an example to your original post showing what you are currently trying?

Comment: @JohnNyingi Modified the answer after update to question.

Comment: have you tested this?